# Android API level 16 is doesn't display any icon except its background wall paper in emulator

Tags: android

I've download everything for AVD API level 16. but after i create AVD of API level 16 and run it following thing happens:
1. Lock screen appears with some background wall paper.
2. After unlocked there is no icon or widget or anything except the background image.
I am very frustrated by this and i am just a beginner of android programming.
Please help if some body have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the screenshot of your AVD settings and also the screenshot of the AVD Emulator after you unlocked it.

With that in place, I should be able to help you. For your reference I'm adding a sample screenshot [image]